# Pseudocode into C

Tags: c, pseudocode

how can I rewrite this into C?

```
for i = 1; i <= N && !quit; i++
        {
        for j = 1; i <= N && !quit; j++
             {
             quit = x(i,j) equals y(i,j)
             }
        }
```

I've tried something like this

```
    for (i = 1; i >= 1; i++)
        {
        for j = 1; j >= 1; j++)
            {
            if (x==y)
                  printf("Good");
            else
                  continue;
            }
        }
```

But I think it's total nonsence and I just can't figure out the right solution. The program shoud count two equations `x=a+u*i`; `y=b+v*j`, where I know `a, b, u, v` and I need `(x=y)`, else repeat until `x=y`. If it cannot be equal, it would `printf("Wrong")`.

Comment: Check on difference between assignment operator and equality operator

Comment: Your C code should probably look a lot more like the pseudo-code. It looks like `x` and `y` should be functions or maybe arrays depending on the "syntax" of the pseudo code.  Also, if `x` and `y` are arrays, you may need to adjust some things due to C having 0-based arrays while many pseudo-code descriptions assume 1-based arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i=1; i <= N && !quit; i++)
{
    for (j=1; j <= N && !quit; j++)
     {
            if (x==y){
                printf("Good");
                break;
            }

            if(j==N && i==N && x!=y){
                printf("Wrong");
            }

     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the following code:

```
unsigned i;
    unsigned j;
    bool quit = false;
    for (i = 1; i <= N && !quit; i++)
    {
       for (j = 1; j <= N && !quit; j++)
       {
          if (x[i][j] == y[i][j])
          {
             quit = true;
          }
       }
    }
```

I assumed that x and y are global arrays like following:

```
int x[N+1][N+1] = { 0 };
int y[N+1][N+1] = { 0 };
```

Rearange your code for your needs.